# The Old Republic Galactic Trade Network successful sell with no credit?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Recently I have put several items onto the Galactic Trade Network (GTN) for selling.
I have 3 items which can be sold successfully, and I can receive 3 mails for successful sell confirmation.

However, for the 3 mails, only one contains the credits which I should receive. For the other 2, they have only mentioned that the credit will be sent to me with a hour.

I have waited for a day, but still I cannot receive my credits.

So I would like to know if anyone have encountered similar situation.
Is it related to my account type? (I am a preferred player).

Comment: Could it possibly have been a single mail with all three sales?

Comment: @fbueckert Nope, there's always one credit mail per sale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the mails take more than an hour, [as confirmed by Customer Support](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=5177389&postcount=2), but you should file a ticket if it gets ridiculous:

> You may need to wait some time for the money to be delivered. If it hasn't arrived a few hours after your item sold, please create a ticket with as many details as possible(item, price, approximate times) and we'll investigate.

And [here](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=5488384&postcount=9):

> Any user experiencing this loss of GTN mails should [Contact Us](http://www.swtor.com/support/form) for investigation into your individual cases.

Note that sometimes the "1 hour" mails [don't show up or don't auto-delete](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=5284007&postcount=10) which could be confusing you.  Most of the time I pop open my mail and hit select all, then get all attachments; as such I miss a lot of the contents.  Whenever I've wondered if I missed getting a payment I've assumed that I just grabbed it without thinking.  Perhaps you're doing the same thing?

In any case it is certainly not related to your account type; Preferred players get all credits from the items they sell (minus the normal GTN fee and any extra if you go over the 350k credit cap), just like subscribers.

Comment: I can hit select all and get all the attachments at only one time??!!
That's such a great function!!! I am quite a rookie for this game so still haven't explored all the functions of this game. I gotta try this later.
I better wait for some time more and check with the CS later.
Thanks a lot for your suggestion.